# SSRS Repeat page header on every page

Tags: reporting-services, header, ssrs-tablix

I have a rectangle and inside the rectangle I have a few tables, text boxes, and then there is one table that contains just the data for the page header.

The rectangle and all subsequent tables are grouped by an id and in between each group is a page break.

I'm having trouble getting the page header to repeat for each new page within the group. When one of the tables inside the rectangle has so many rows it pushes the report to another page as expected so the report could be 2 pages long etc.. and I can't get the page header to show on the subsequent page. Only on the first or second page of the report etc... based on where in the rectangle I put the table that contains the page header data, this table is hidden when the report is run and is only providing the data for the page header.

Is there any way I can get the data in the table to repeat on every page so that it displays in every pages' page header or another way of getting the data to repeat on every page so that for every page within my group it shows the same page header.

I see that a tablix has the "repeat header row on each page" but this doesn't seem to work because its not this tablix that is causing multiple pages to happen but rather the other tablixes and textboxes and its not always the same one. Any of them could roll over to the next page so this setting won't work for my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeating a page header on every page is not possible when the page header includes items that are referenced within the report body and those items do not exist on that specific page.